# How can I use sed to only print what appears between these two strings?

Tags: sed

How can I use sed to only post what appears between iterations of:

```
    "<title><![DATA["
```

and

```
     ]]></title>
```

I tried doing

```
     sed 's/<title><![DATA[/(.*)/]]//g'
```

but it just prints the whole file

Comment: It looks like you are using regular expressions to parse HTML. That is in general not a good idea unless you have extreme tight control over what is in the "DATA" section.

Comment: Seeing a complete document which is representative of what you have, would be helpful. That would make it possible for us to come up with a solution that would work for all cases.  If this is an XML document, I would expect to see a `CDATA` section instead of a `DATA` section, and I would not expect to see double quotes around the tags as you show. Could you possibly check to see that you are showing the correct information?

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're looking for can be accomplished with this:

```
$ sed -n '/<title><![DATA[/,/]]></title>/p' /path/to/file
```

This is using the first pattern, `/<title><![DATA[/` as the beginning match, followed by a comma (<kbd>,</kbd>). This tells `sed` we want everything in between. We then tell `sed` what we want at the other end of this range, `/]]></title>/`.

Comment: thanks but for some reason, what happens, is it finds the first instance of the first pattern and the last instance of the second pattern, and prints eveything in between. I need it to individually print everything that shows up between instances of the two patterns.

Comment: You would need to test this. At the moment, it tries to execute the `t` command to jump to the label `itle>/p`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `grep` could be more useful than `sed` for such job:

```
grep -Po '(?<=<title><!\[DATA\[).+(?=\]\]></title>)' your_file.html
```

prints everything included in the pattern excluding the pattern itself

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Anthon, but for a limited scope and if it appears only once on the same line, this is an adaptation to your sed script:

```
sed 's|<title><!\[DATA\[\(.*\)\]\].*|\1|g'
```